# Ajax, checkboxes & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Needing a little help please.
I have this:
[image]

Which allows users to select more than one item, I need to gather if its selected and what the value is which is the title of the item in this case.

I also have this ajax currently:

```
  $('.box').on('change', function(event) {


         var valueName = $('#box').val();



            var checked = $('input[name=checked]:checked');
             if( checked.length > 0 ) {
                  var checkValues = checked.map(function(){
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();                        
                     $.ajax({
                          url: 'accessories_post.php',
                          type: 'post',
                          data: { checked: checkValues },
                          success:function(data){ console.log(data); }
                     });
                }
```

Which posts to accessories_post.php which has

```
 print_r($_POST['checked']);
```

But then when I want to grab this data and put into a variable i need to then send via mail any ideas why im not getting anything for this.

Comment: It's probably an array. You have to loop through it.

Comment: foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $checked)

$checked

endforeach

??

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `$checked` variable inside..?

Comment: Give me example if you will. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST['checked']);` output for you?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['title'] ;?>" name="checked" class="box" id="box">  is the checkbox!

Comment: print_r($_POST['checked']); outputs nothing

Comment: print_r($_POST) produces Array ( )

Comment: Does all your checkbox have the same `id`? If so, that is invalid. Also do a `console.log(checkValues);` before the ajax.

Comment: Yes they all have the same id because its in a while loop

Comment: console.log is showing the following image http://cl.ly/image/1G331F342i2Y

Comment: If so, then you can append a number to the `id` and increment it while looping. Do you see any output for `checkValues` in your console?

Comment: How does one append a number and increment it i need to get this working like yesterday

Comment: Alright clarifying one more thing, should the AJAX fire every time you click on a checkbox or maybe on some button click?

Comment: It fires everythime I click a different checkbox so that's fine, also here's the PHP - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11175622

Comment: So now i need to post the checkboxes that's been selected to the mail() function in order to send it via email saying Mr Smith wants to order Mud Guard and Door Mats etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `.map` function, you can simply do:

```
 checkValues = '';
 $('input[name="checked"]:checked').each(function(){
     checkValues+=$(this).val()+",";
 });
 //this is to remove the extra comma , at the end of the string
 checkValues = checkValues.substring(0,(checkValues.length-1));
```

I've concatenated the checkbox values, so `$_POST['checked']` will return values like *title,title2* etc.

And regarding the increment of `id` value that you had asked, you can do something like:

```
$i=0;
//your loop statement starts
 echo "<input type='checkbox' id='box{$i}' name='checked'>";
 $i++;
//loop ends
```

Comment: So in the mail() function for the selected part do i just say $_POST['checked']; ??

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Yes. But consider running your AJAX on some button click instead of on change of every checkbox.

Comment: any suggestions? how best way to that?

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Just put the above code with the AJAX function on the click of submit button?

Comment: @the_unforgiven_II Yes, that looks fine, is the `name`, `email` and `tel` also passed from the same page? If yes, pass those parameters in your AJAX too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51183/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-the-unforgiven-ii)